# I'm "done" with my apple pie

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to say "I'm done with my apple pie" to indicate that you are finished eating it. I don't want to necessarily imply that I didn't like it.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between "I have finished eating it" and "I am finished eating it".

Comment: One of my friends used to say, "Potatoes are *done*..." but  I think this is really prescriptivist, and nobody I know observes this distinction 100% of the time.  We say we're done all the time to indicate we've finished eating no matter what the reason.

Comment: If you really don't want to imply you didn't like it, "done" is... well, brusque. "I've had enough, thanks. It was delicious." is *nicer*, though *done* is correct as well.

Comment: "I'm done with my apple pie" is perfectly fine and reasonably idiomatic.  "I'm finished with my apple pie" might be a hair better, since "done" can carry a negative connotation if (accidentally?) emphasized (even though there's no such connotation if not emphasized).

Comment: You should not use "grammatically correct" when asking how it would sound.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is grammatically correct, yes. It could mean either that you've eaten all of your apple pie ("I'm done with my apple pie; is there any more left?"), or that you've eaten as much as you'd like to ("I'm done with my apple pie; does anyone want the rest?"). It does not necessarily imply that you didn't like it, but if you say this after eating only a little bit, people will likely infer as much.

Comment: Very nice answer. +1